# How to confidently attract the other party to your side?

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, structure, word-choice

I have the following sentence:

> Once they realize they have no chance of defeating you, they'll end up joining you.

I feel this sentence may come across as a bit "cocky" because I would want the opposing party to join my side, but at the same time, I feel that if they feel insulted, they could decide not to join even though they know they will lose because they were offended.

Comment: Well, you're already assuming that the only two choices is to join your side or to lose.

Comment: That's the message I don't want to be received. I don't want the oppositive party to feel threaten or that they have no choice, but that joining my side is the best solution for them.

Comment: Are you taking about the reader or another character in fiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Together nothing can stop us.

The problem with your intial idea is that you are saying that you are invincible for them. You are positioning yourself as a threat that can't be overcome, challenging them and at the same time insulting their abilities by mocking that they won't ever be able to be on par with you.

You can say something like your initial idea to a third party in secret to explain your plan if you are trying to win them over by demonstrating your powers in front of the opposing party. In that case your sentence works perfectly to convey the idea and explain your actions, but you have to make sure never to say something like that directly to the party you are trying to win.

Working together is a great thing and nobody ever needs to know that you think you are better than them. You just want them to join you so that both of you can profit from this and be more powerful than before.